I need help solving a non-elementary integral
This is the integral
$\frac{4}{3} \pi \int_{0}^{15} x \sqrt{(x + \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}}  dx$
I got as far as trying to substitute
$\sqrt{(x + \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}} = u$
But I can't do it so I try
$(x + \frac{1}{2}) = u$
which give me
$\frac{4}{3} \pi \int_{1\over2}^{31\over2} (u + \frac{1}{2}) \sqrt{u^2 - \frac{1}{4}}  dx$
I did try to integrate by part but it gets me no where.
It would be great if I can get some help on the technique or how to start evaluating this.

Whenever you have any question please first search on Approach Zero before asking as there are high chances that your question has already been asked and answered years ago here or on AoPS already see search results for your this integral on ApproachZero

$\int_0^{15} x\sqrt{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}dx=\int_0^{15} x\sqrt{x^2+x}dx$
Here, write x as $\frac{1}{2}(2x+1)-\frac{1}{2}$ and substitute $u=x^2+x$. I am pretty sure you can take it further from here.

Hey there, Thanks a lot for the suggestion and the help, though it seem like my question is similar when simplify to another question. So I will have to close my question down but still, thanks!

@congle No problem ${}$

An unrelated question, but may I know any helpful books to study elementary calculus?

HINT
Try to apply the substitution
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\cosh(z) := x + \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Hey there, Thanks a lot for the suggestion and the help, though it seem like my question is similar when simplify to another question. So I will have to close my question down but still, thanks!
